# Why is my external script not working in my HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, external-script

I'm quite new to coding.

Basically, I'm trying to use the below external JS file in my HTML but it doesn't work when I include this in my HTML file:

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox/satellite-v9',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoidGhhaWxlZSIsImEiOiJjbDFxYmUzZGwxZWFzM2lxcjJkOWNmZmlsIn0.B57x2tvc2UbNrR1jdV0nrg'
}).addTo(map);
```

But when I include these codes in the same script tag in HTML, it works? My html code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Map</title>
        <meta name="description" content="thai Yik Lee Portfolio">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
        crossorigin=""/>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>MAP</h1>
        <div id="map" style="height: 500px">
            Here
        </div>
        
        <script src="/libs/map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: @Grumpy, not there is no error in my code. When I run the js code directly in the script tag in the HTML, the map runs, but when I put the code externally in a separate JS file, my map does not load up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, the path to my file had an extra '/'

Comment: Please mark this as solved. Also, you should do ./libs/map.js instead of libs/map.js